# SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a stored procedure that inserts a `varchar` & `VARBINARY(MAX)` values in the table.
I pass a c# `byte[]` to the `varbinary(max)` field. I also see that the size of the `byte[]` size is 80142 which satisfies the max limit of `varbinary`. Stored procedure executes without any errors. But when I try to query that table I see empty values in the `varbinary` datatype.

SQL sp

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] 
            -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            @PNumber varchar(50)
            ,@Byte varbinary(max)
        AS
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            -- Insert statements for procedure here
            INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Data]
                   ([PNumber]
                   ,[PByte])
             VALUES
                   (@PNumber
                   ,@Byte)
        END
```

C# CODE

```
byte[] theData = doc.GetData();

DAL_DataTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter qta = new DAL_DataTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();

qta.Test("test", theData);
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PNumber] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [PByte] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to do the `insert`? (Both the stored procedure definition and the `C#` call) Also what do you mean by "empty" values `null` or `0x`?

Comment: Please see the code i added . I just see a blank line in the pbytes  column

Comment: Please add the CREATE script for the Data table.

Comment: Your first sentence says that you're inserting an int and varbinary, but the rest of the post seems to be dealing with a varchar and varbinary. It may be best to run SQL Server profiler and see what the actual SQL call is that SQL server is getting.

Comment: I have a vague "recollection" (it may be entirely wrong and if so apologies for any confusion caused!) that you might need to pass the length of the byte array. Is there an overload that accepts a length parameter?

Comment: Have you launched SQL Profiler to see what query really gets sent to SQL Server?? What happens if you call that stored proc from SQL Server Mgmt Studio?? Does it properly insert data into your table??

Comment: Not sure but seems like the `c#` tag wouldn't be redundant here.

Comment: @Andriy - I agree. This needs to be tagged such that .NET programmers see it. Pretty sure that the `tsql` end is fine. Not sure I've necessarily chosen the right tags though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you determine that the data is empty? I'm quite certain that SQL Server Management Studio will not display a value that is too long (I don't know the limit), even when the value is there.

Comment: SSMS truncates the data returned though it doesn't just not display any.

Comment: I don't have access to SSMS right now, so I can't check. I know for a fact, though, that for XML data it will just show it as blank if it is too long.